# Are entry door systems with lock release secure?

Tags: electrical, lock

I am renovating my recently bought house. It currently has a entry door system with a lock release on the yale lock so that you can release the door from one of the handsets. [something like this](http://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/DE901.html).

I have handsets all over the house so I opened up the entry system outside (1 screw) to make sense of all the wiring and realised that I could short circuit the power and lock wire and open the door from outside.

I would have thought that it would be more sensible if the door release circuit was not exposed outside.

Is this how they all work?

Surely this isn't secure?

Can I improve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I am inferring correctly what you are describing, it sounds like the "brains" of the system are installed outside with one screw access. That, of course, is an abysmal design. The only thing that should be outside accessible would be the wires to the call button and speaker - all other wiring should be inside-access only.

If you are otherwise happy with the system, you could probably move the components that should not be outside inside, leaving only the wiring needed for the outside components running to the outside box.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of that system, but that certainly is not "how they all work". The box outside should only be an intercom in the one you've shown us. If there was a keypad to unlock the door, that would only send key-press signals rather than connecting directly to the latch. The wire which operates the latch should *NOT* be exposed.

Either you're misreading the circuit, or someone was incompetent when they designed it (unlikely), or someone was clueless when they installed it (fairly likely).

Answer (score 0):

The system to which the question links lists [this](http://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/DE204.html) "Flush Mortice Lock Release
12v AC/DC - Fail Secure" under the heading *Related Items You May Need".

If the lock is in a locked state, it remains locked upon interruption of power just as one would respect of a competently designed system component.

Comment: I believe that @user18909 is describing **applying** power to the lock wire, not **removing** it; but I'll admit that could be less vague.

Comment: The premise of the question is that the system is poorly designed. That is inconsistent with the link and industry practice...e.g. the electrical release control is typically intended to be installed on the secured side of the door and manually operated by the occupants of the structure not those wishing to gain access. Of course it is possible for those without experience with such systems to install them incorrectly, but that is another matter.